# open SharePoint designer by another account

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I have two SharePoint accounts and I tried to open SharePoint designer by another account, and I switched account to my second account,

but the Issue is when I create workflows and publish it, from the information of workflow the last modified by gives me the first account?

How can I solve this to publish the workflow by second account?

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote and mark the answer as accepted in case it helped you! you have more than 10 questions without any action from your side, in case you have any comment or need more clarification you should comment the answer owner to help you! otherwise, you should close the question by upvoting and mark the correct answer as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Switch account** in Account Section is not mean you have signed in to SharePoint Designer site `as a different user`.

[image]

---

**To log in as a different user for Sharepoint Designer do the following**

1. Start  SharePoint Designer `as a Different User` option, by holding the Shift key with right-click on the SharePoint Designer icon.

[image]

2. Sometimes the above option is not worked with SharePoint Designer so try to do the following

   - Open Internet Explorer.
   - Open Tools menu and go to Internet Options.
   - Select the Security Tab.
   - Select the Intranet Zone (Or your affected zone if your SharePoint site is not in your Intranet)
   - Click the button for Custom Level.
   - Find “User Authentication” in the list.
   - Set this option to “Prompt for Username and Password”.
   - Open SharePoint Designer > open your site, you should prompt now to enter your second account credential.
   - Save and publish your workflow you should see the last modified user is the current login user.

[image]

I mentioned all details steps at [SIGN IN AS DIFFERENT USER IN SHAREPOINT DESIGNER 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/10/03/sign-in-as-different-user-in-sharepoint-designer-2013/)